# Running cmd (in Win+R) opens black terminal console

Tags: windows-10, terminal

Windows 10 [Version 10.0.18362.207].

A strange thing happened after I changed settings for the terminal (played with fonts and legacy mode) and return back to original (actually default).

Now when I run cmd (in Win+R) it opens black terminal console (without command prompt).

If I switch to the `legacy mode` it opens ok, with command prompt, though I don't want to work with `legacy mode` terminal.

If I open a terminal using icons and start menu, it opens ok.

I wonder if someone has met such a problem, what can be advice to fix it?

Comment: Can you verify that the font color is not set to the same as your background color?

Comment: Yes definitely color is ok.. )

Comment: BTW maybe the problem was with color, but it didn't appy the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console key solved this!